# Python run out of memory on mac

Tags: python, object, for-loop

I am currently using python on a Mac.
The task is to to scrape something from the web and store it in a csv file.
What my problem right now is that
if i create a new object in `for` loop lets say

```
for x in list:
   y = classvar()
   with open("test.csv") as f:
       f.write(y)
```

where classvar() contains several dictionaries.

After around 1000 iterations, my mac crashes saying I don't have enough memory!
I am just wondering what is the best solution to this?
Should I use `del y` at the end of each for loop?

Comment: `open("test.csv")` opens the file for *reading*; `f.write(y)` tries to write to it. This doesn't make sense.

Comment: `open()` inside a `for` is extremely inefficient as it unnecessarily open the file multiple times.

Comment: "at the end of each for loop"? I only see one.

Comment: sorry guys, the code it should be open("test.csv","wb") but you get the idea

Comment: And i kinda needs to open the file during each loop because the data may be corrupted so open it in each loop kinda saves the data? I don't know....

Comment: If you're opening the file with "wb" each time, you're overwriting the previous iteration's output anyway. Either open with "ab" or, preferably, put the `for` loop inside the `with` statement. I'm not sure what kind of corruption you think can be avoided by repeated closing and (re)opening the file.

Comment: sorry, i meant "ab", For example, if i opened my file outside of the for loop and i decide to keyboard interrupt my process, does the file still gets saved?

Comment: Yes; when a file is used as a context manager (i.e., with the `with` statement, the file is *always* closed properly, even in the event of an exception. You don't necessarily have control over how *much* of any particular `write` manages to write to the file before that happens, though, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: What exactly does `classvar()` return? The code you've posted doesn't appear to do anything that would cause memory to be used up over time.

Comment: classvar() is just a custom object with some dictionaries in it. what im trying to do is get information from web, store it in the classvar object and write it to a file. the reason i am storing it in classvar is to make it organized. I am assuming that each time i create a classvar in the for loop, it takes memory? since python only garbage collects unreferenced variables after exiting a scope, the memory accumulates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `y` is something that is big, and isn't needed except in one iteration of the loop, you should use `with` on it as well:

```
for x in list:
   with classvar() as y:
       with open("test.csv", "w") as f:
           f.write(y)
```

`classvar()` needs to have `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, and the `__exit__` method should clean the object up.

Comment: might be worth mentioning not to use list as a variable name

Comment: I'm pretty sure Quinn isn't posting the actual code, so the real list probably has a better name.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. Just out of curiosity is there a benefit of using with rather than create at beginning and delete it at the end of the loop?

Comment: Not every variable assignment is amenable to use in a `with` statement. `classvar()` needs to return an object whose type defines `__exit__` and `__enter__` methods.

Comment: You're also making the assumption that `type(y).__exit__` (if it exists) will do more to free up memory than simply letting the former object be garbage-collected.

Comment: If i wish to free memory of the class in __exit__, how would i do that since what im doing is calling a function inside the class to delete the class. is that even possible?

Comment: `__exit__` needs to delete any indirect references in the class's contents. (Remember, every Python variable is really a reference to a value.) Examples would be if the in-class dictionaries referred to each other, or if the objects in the dictionaries referred to each other or to the parent object. Sometimes you can use the `weakref` module to deal with this in a more automatic fashion.